# Run no more than 4 processes at a time in parallel in shell

Tags: shell, unix, ubuntu

Currently I'm stuck at running time consuming simulations efficiently. The intention is to run 4 simulations in parallel, because it's a single thread application and a quad core system. I have to variations of shell script:

```
./sim -r 1 &
./sim -r 2 &
./sim -r 3 &
./sim -r 4 &
wait
./sim -r 5 &
./sim -r 6 &
./sim -r 7 &
./sim -r 8 &
wait
... (another 112 jobs)
```

with this code there is a wait again and again. I also tried to split the tasks into four scripts and run each, result is that one script is finished while the other has about 30% of remaining jobs. I can't predict how long a simulation will take.

Any suggestion to have 4 simulations running at any time?

Comment: Interesting question.  AFAIK, it can't be done in `bash` (or Korn shell, or Bourne shell, or POSIX shell).  You can either wait for a specific process(`bash`) or for all processes (all of them), but not for one of a group of processes at a time. I'd probably use Perl (or Python, perhaps) to do the running; it can wait for any of the processes to die and then launch another.

Comment: I have written a script in bash to check running processes, if you are interested, check example in https://github.com/kmagusiak/bashf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install the `moreutils` package in Ubuntu, then use the `parallel` utility:

```
parallel -j 4 ./sim -r -- 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ...
```

Comment: Linux manual page for [`parallel()`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/parallel).  GNU [tutorial](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html) for `parallel`.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to install the `parallel` utility (which looks neat assuming it works as indicated), then you could adapt this Perl script (basically, changing the command that is executed), and probably reducing the monitoring:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use constant MAX_KIDS => 4;

$| = 1;

my %pids;
my $kids = 0;   # Number of kids

for my $i (1..20)
{
    my $pid;
    if (($pid = fork()) == 0)
    {
        my $tm = int(rand() * (10 - 2) + 2);
        print "sleep $tm\n";
        # Using exec in a block on its own is the documented way to
        # avoid the warning:
        # Statement unlikely to be reached at filename.pl line NN.
        #   (Maybe you meant system() when you said exec()?)
        # Yes, I know the print and exit statements should never be
        # reached, but, dammit, sometimes things go wrong!
        { exec "sleep", $tm; }
        print STDERR "Oops: couldn't sleep $tm!\n";
        exit 1;
    }
    $pids{$pid} = 1;
    $kids++;
    my $time = time;
    print "PID: $pid; Kids: $kids; Time: $time\n";
    if ($kids >= MAX_KIDS)
    {
        my $kid = waitpid(-1, 0);
        print "Kid: $kid ($?)\n";
        if ($kid != -1)
        {
            delete $pids{$kid};
            $kids--;
        }
    }
}

while ((my $kid = waitpid(-1, 0)) > 0)
{
    my $time = time;
    print "Kid: $kid (Status: $?); Time: $time\n";
    delete $pids{$kid};
    $kids--;
}

# This should not do anything - and doesn't (any more!).
foreach my $pid (keys %pids)
{
    printf "Undead: $pid\n";
}
```

Example output:

```
PID: 20152; Kids: 1; Time: 1383436882
PID: 20153; Kids: 2; Time: 1383436882
sleep 5
PID: 20154; Kids: 3; Time: 1383436882
sleep 7
sleep 9
PID: 20155; Kids: 4; Time: 1383436882
sleep 4
Kid: 20155 (0)
PID: 20156; Kids: 4; Time: 1383436886
sleep 4
Kid: 20152 (0)
PID: 20157; Kids: 4; Time: 1383436887
sleep 2
Kid: 20153 (0)
PID: 20158; Kids: 4; Time: 1383436889
sleep 9
Kid: 20157 (0)
PID: 20159; Kids: 4; Time: 1383436889
sleep 6
Kid: 20156 (0)
PID: 20160; Kids: 4; Time: 1383436890
sleep 6
Kid: 20154 (0)
PID: 20161; Kids: 4; Time: 1383436891
sleep 9
Kid: 20159 (0)
PID: 20162; Kids: 4; Time: 1383436895
sleep 7
Kid: 20160 (0)
PID: 20163; Kids: 4; Time: 1383436896
sleep 9
Kid: 20158 (0)
PID: 20164; Kids: 4; Time: 1383436898
sleep 6
Kid: 20161 (0)
PID: 20165; Kids: 4; Time: 1383436900
sleep 9
Kid: 20162 (0)
PID: 20166; Kids: 4; Time: 1383436902
sleep 9
Kid: 20164 (0)
PID: 20167; Kids: 4; Time: 1383436904
sleep 2
Kid: 20163 (0)
PID: 20168; Kids: 4; Time: 1383436905
sleep 6
Kid: 20167 (0)
PID: 20169; Kids: 4; Time: 1383436906
sleep 9
Kid: 20165 (0)
PID: 20170; Kids: 4; Time: 1383436909
sleep 4
Kid: 20168 (0)
PID: 20171; Kids: 4; Time: 1383436911
Kid: 20166 (0)
sleep 9
Kid: 20170 (Status: 0); Time: 1383436913
Kid: 20169 (Status: 0); Time: 1383436915
Kid: 20171 (Status: 0); Time: 1383436920
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NUMJOBS=30
NUMPOOLS=4

seq 1 "$NUMJOBS" | for p in $(seq 1 $NUMPOOLS); do
    while read x; do ./sim -r "$x"; done &
done
```

The `for` loop creates a pool of background processes which reads from the shared standard input to start a simulation. Each background process "blocks" while its simulation is running, then reads the next job number from the `seq` command.

Without the `for` loop, it might be a little easier to follow:

```
seq 1 "$NUMJOBS" | {
    while read x; do ./sim -r "$x"; done &
    while read x; do ./sim -r "$x"; done &
    while read x; do ./sim -r "$x"; done &
    while read x; do ./sim -r "$x"; done &
}
```

Assuming `sim` takes a non-trivial amount of time to run, the first `while` will read 1 from its standard input, the 2nd 2, etc. Whichever `sim` finishes first, that `while` loop will `read` 5 from standard input; the next to finish will read 6, and so on. Once the last simulation is started, each `read` will fail, causing the loop to exit.