# Doing 2 functions through loop in one pass

Tags: bash

I've developed a bash script to do some network scanning. However, I'd like to improve the functionality by making it do 2 scans at once. My code looks like this:

```
for d in `seq 0 255` ;
    do 
        echo 17.6.3.$d
        sudo nmap -pT:80,22 17.4.1.$d       
    done
```

So at the moment it scans all IP addresses in the subnet /24, 1 by 1 and in order. I'd like some help to make it scan in pairs, so 17.6.3.1 and 17.6.3.2 at the same time, then 17.6.3.3 and 17.6.3.4 and so on until 255. Thanks.

Comment: Probably GNU `parallel`.  Maybe [Shell: run four processes in parallel](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19747644) can help.

Comment: Is there a reason you are breaking this up this way? nmap can take `CIDR` ranges/etc. as targets directly. `nmap -pT:80,22 17.4.1.0/24`, etc.

Comment: I plan on scanning multiple ports and I need to break them up into pairs to ensure the IDS is not triggered.

Answer (score 0):

From [bash hackers wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/c_for):

```
for((x = 0; x < 256; x += 2)); do
  echo 17.6.3.$x
  echo 17.6.3.$((x+1))
  # etc.
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the same:

```
seq 0 255 | parallel -j2 echo 17.6.3.{}\; sudo nmap -pT:80,22 17.4.1.{}
```

Personally I would do this:

```
parallel -j200 --tag sudo nmap -pT:80,22 ::: 17.4.1.{1..254}
```