# Limiting job submission using xargs

Tags: bash, unix, xargs

I have more than 1000 lines in a file(say run.txt) each line will be submitting a job. As there are more lines so all jobs are submitting.  But I want to limit job submission to 300 all the time. I used the `sleep` command after 300 lines but if jobs are in wait state then again next set of jobs are submitted which is not acceptable. 
I used xargs as follows:

```
printf %s\\0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -P 300 run.txt
```

I am seeing that more than 300 jobs will be submitted. Please correct me.

Comment: I don't think `xargs` has that sort of scheduling capability.  I don't know that `parallel` does either — it might.  You probably need a custom program to do that — shell script, or Perl script.  ISTR doing something similar in a previous SO question some years ago.  Whether I can find it is another matter altogether.

Comment: You can find a similar situation in SO 1974-7644 [Shell: run four processes in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747644). The code in my answer uses Perl and generates the jobs with a random sleep, so you would need to replace that with code that reads the jobs from the file instead. Obviously, from the question title, the limit there is 4 and not 300; that's trivially fixed. I'd read the command in the main process, not in the forked child process. And now that I look at the answers to that question, the `parallel` program does indeed have a `-j 300` option that you need to use.

Comment: GNU `parallel` has the `-P`option for controlling how many jobs are run at once, if I'm reading the documentation right.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what do you think the `printf` does?  And shouldn't you be redirecting the input from `run.txt`?